# Bash script to remove small images

Tags: image, bash, awk, delete-file

I didn't write the script I'm about to paste, I found it and modified it slightly because I don't know how to do it myself. Here is the current code:

```
for F in *.jpg *.gif ; do
identify "$F"
done | awk '{ split($3, wh, /x/); } wh[1] < 800 && wh[2] < 800 { print $1 }'
```

This works and displays images with dimensions less than 800px in either dimension.
But if I try to change it to this:

```
for F in *.jpg *.gif ; do
identify "$F"
done | awk '{ split($3, wh, /x/); } wh[1] < 800 && wh[2] < 800 { rm -vfr $1 }'
```

Nothing happens, nothing is deleted, why not?

Comment: _"nothing is deleted, why not?":_  Because `rm -vfr $1` is a shell command placed inside of an `awk` script and `awk` supports `awk` commands, not shell commands.

Comment: An **unsafe** way, without much change in your code is: `awk... { print "rm -vfr '"$1"';"} | bash`

Answer (score 4):

`rm` is a *shell* command, not an `awk` command.

One way to do what you want is to use `awk` just to print the file names (which it *can* do) and then pipe that into something that's capable of deleting:

```
for F in *.jpg *.gif ; do
    identify "$F"
done | awk '{split($3,wh,/x/);} wh[1]<800 && wh[2]<800 {print $1}' | xargs rm
```

I haven't checked whether any of your other code is valid, I'm assuming it is because the script was working before you made your changes.

`xargs` will receive a list of things on its standard input and batch them up to have a specific command run against them. So, for example, the following sequence:

```
touch paxjunk001
touch paxjunk002
echo paxjunk* | xargs rm
```

will effectively be the same as:

```
touch paxjunk001
touch paxjunk002
rm paxjunk001 paxjunk002
```

Getting it to handle the "weird" file names such as those with spaces in them, is a matter of using NUL characters as the separator rather than white space.

That means your `awk` `print` command will turn into something like:

```
{ printf "%s\0", $1 }`
```

to get the filenames separated correctly, and using:

```
xargs --null
```

to ensure `xargs` understands the format.

Comment: Many thanks, I'm find it hard to explain how I understand what you mean - although I do!

Maybe: I'm speaking to the program xargs from the first quotation marks to the end, not the shell, and therefore it is the interpreter for the commands I'm giving it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using ImageMagick, you can defer to `identify` the test about the size of your image. The `-format` switch to `identify` is very powerful and allows a lot of computations to be done.

For example:

```
identify -format '%[fx:w<800 && h<800]' image.jpg
```

will output to stdout 1 if the image has a width less than 800px and a height less than 800px, and outputs 0 otherwise. Using this is much safer than your solution of parsing the raw output of `identify`, since your solution breaks as soon as a filename contains a space.

I would suggest using something along these lines instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
for f in *.jpg *.gif; do
    a=$(identify -format '%[fx:w<800 && h<800]' -- "$f") || continue
    if [[ $a = 1 ]]; then
        echo rm -v -- "$f"
    fi
done
```

This will only echo the `rm` commands, and will not perform them. Remove the `echo` command in front of `rm` if you're happy with what you see.

For more information about these features of ImageMagick, please see these links:

- [ImageMagick's escapes](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/escape.php),
- [ImageMagick's `fx` operator](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/fx.php).